# Any Method to Get number of LIKES of a URL or PAGE of Facebook?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

i am trying to show number of likes on my website of my page but i dont want that facebook widget. Please help me - Any API Request that i can use to pull number of likes.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this easily with Facebook Graph API.

There are two options:

1. if you want to get number of likes of some Page or URL, use this piece of code:

   ```
   https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select%20like_count%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url=%27http://www.facebook.com/facebook/%27&format=json
   ```

   NOTE that you need to change the part where i wrote URL that's `http://www.facebook.com/facebook`
2. The New Graph API provides a minimal pull request code e.g.

   ```
   http://graph.facebook.com/[Type your Page USERNAME here]?fields=likes
   ```

   Here replace `[Type your page username]` part with username e.g.

   ```
   http://graph.facebook.com/facebook?fields=likes`
   ```

   and it will give you an output like:

   ```
   {
     "id": "20531316728",
     "likes": 92990262
   }
   ```

   I hope this helps and fulfills your purpose.